# Is there a way to script setting up a space (mission control) in OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, productivity, osx-spaces, mission-control

It seems that Spaces was designed with assigning apps to a space in mind (see [this KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1624)).  Even apps like TotalSpaces are [built with this model](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/apps).  This seems redundant to me as there is already an app switcher (Cmd-Tab) that lets you switch between applications.

I'd like to use Spaces as a way to switch between **projects**.  So for example, I have a space for ProjectA that has a window each for XCode, Safari, Sublime Text, and Terminal.  Then I have a different space for ProjectB that also has a window each for XCode, Safari, Sublime Text, and Terminal.  It's just that the windows have different documents open.

But maintaining the setup is inconvenient, because I have to set them up over and over again, and it is particularly terrible when I flit back and forth between computers, and have to open five windows and get them into the right space myself.  Is there some way I can generate a one-step script that sets up a space the way I like it automatically?  Shareware, Applescript, etc.?  Or am I just trying to shoehorn my working style into a feature that was built for someone else?

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. I wrote an AppleScript some time ago to perform the tedious task of opening a Terminal window in every space.

Most of the examples on the internet ultimately use AppleScript to generate keystrokes. For instance, if you have it set up so "control-2" takes you to space 2 (this can be set in the "keyboard" preference pane), you can use the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
                keystroke "2" using control down --switches to space 2
        end tell
end tell
```

to change to space 2. So my script, which opens a Terminal window in each space, works like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
            keystroke "1" using control down --switches to space 1
    end tell
    tell process "Terminal"
            activate
            keystroke "t" using command down --new terminal tab
    end tell
    tell process "Finder"
            keystroke "2" using control down --switches to space 2
    end tell
    ...etc...
end tell
```

Clearly, you can instruct applications other than Terminal to open windows in a given space.

You can launch a non-running app with `do shell script "open -a application_name"`.

The problem with this approach is that it is entirely dependent on sending keystrokes, where it's possible for them to be sent too fast, end up queued, and ultimately execute in the wrong order. To prevent this it's necessary to add a delay (for instance, `delay 0.1`) after each scripted keystroke, making the entire script take some time to execute.

Or, for instance, if you launch an app, it may take some time to initialize, and it will open its windows in whatever space is active once it gets that far along (as opposed to whatever space was active when you first launched the app). So, the delay must be set appropriately each time, and sometimes it may be several seconds. Even worse, due to system load variances, the time may not even be consistent from execution to execution, forcing you to use a delay long enough to account for the worst-case scenario. (For example, if you launch an app which may take as long as 5 seconds from the moment of execution to display its first window, you'll need to delay 5 seconds before switching to the next space and moving on.)

Unfortunately, I haven't seen another approach to switching spaces. Hopefully someone can come along and provide a better way to switch than sending keystrokes, or perhaps a way to make the script wait without giving an arbitrary delay.

Still, if you don't mind giving your script a few seconds to get your environment up and running, you should be able to easily sequence a series of application launches or window openings and space selections with what I've provided.